# Pix2Pix facede dataset, prevent "gray" in dataset to be predicted

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, gan

I'm trying to build from scratch the pix2pix architecture, the one [on this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07004.pdf).

As they did, I'm using the facade dataset, and this is one of their result:

[image]

I'm particularly interested in the last one, where they have used cGAN+L1, specifically because the dataset is filled with images like that one, where on the borders they have some "black" padding for some reason, and in my test that is causing to have that black part also on the predictions:

[image]

How do you think that they managed to avoid this? As of now, the Gen loss is the sum of the crossentropy and the reconstruction, and in their paper the have a $\lambda$ to scale down the rec loss, so maybe is that, or maybe it's something else that I'm missing, any idea?

Comment: You don't make it clear but your question refers to "Image-to-Image Translation with Conditional Adversarial Networks" https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07004. A good place to start may be Papers with code; see [here](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/image-to-image-translation-with-conditional).

Comment: @dipetkov seeing what others have used just tell you a possible way to do it, not why your one has a problem. Also, this model has 2mil parameters, the suggested architecture around 54mil, which is not easily trainable...